# MySQLi INSERT (prepared statements) not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I've looked through similar questions on here and so have fixed problems like with backticks, but for some reason my code still isn't working, and I'm not getting anything inserted into the table at all. I'd really appreciate a pair of fresh eyes over it to see what's going wrong - it's probably something annoyingly tiny...

```
// Connect
$con = new mysqli( $db_server, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name );

// Check connection
if($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

$user = $_POST['name'];
$pass = password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user`, `pass`) VALUES(?, ?)";

$query = $con->prepare( $sql );
$query->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);

$res = $query->execute();

if (!$res) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $con->error);
}
```

The database itself has a table, "users", which has three columns - uid (autoincrementing unique ID), user and pass.

EDIT: Added error reporting on the execution, and it's giving me the following error statement: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1"

EDIT 2: Updated code.

EDIT 3: Somehow, it's fixed itself. Hm.

Comment: Remove `'ss',` from `bind_param()`

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: Still nothing, I'm afraid :(

Comment: And no error at all.

Comment: @Err Why remove `ss`?

Comment: You aren't checking for errors on the execution. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Why are you saving `$_POST` array in `$form` ?

Comment: Actually, there are no striking errors in that code - if you're not getting anything into the database, I would suggest looking at all possible logs - php-error-logs, apache error-logs and mysql error-logs.

Comment: @chris85 Having added code to check for errors, I'm now getting the following: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1"

Comment: Are your placeholders quoted? This is your real code?

Comment: @oinops save into variables directly from `$_POST` don't use $form.

Comment: @chris85 Placeholders not quoted - this is the exact code as I'm running it, minus the error-checking on the execution I've just added, and the obvious password I've omitted from the top.

Comment: The error comes on the `prepare`, `bind`, or `execute` (sounds like prepare)? Can you update the post to where you've added the error reporting?

Comment: @chris85 Yep, code updated.

Comment: @oinops wow what are you doing there?? Don't use `query`. The `$query->execute()` executes the query.

Comment: @chris85 Oh, brainfog. Fixed it. And somehow, it seems to have fixed itself - data now going into the database. Hm. What did I do?

Comment: Maybe you where using `query` in place of `execute`? That's the only thing I cant think of. The `execute` would have written but the `query` would always error out.